# How to mock userReducer with jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have the below code:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const initialTodos = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Todo 1",
    complete: false,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Todo 2",
    complete: false,
  },
];

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "COMPLETE":
      return state.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === action.id) {
          return { ...todo, complete: !todo.complete };
        } else {
          return todo;
        }
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

function Todos() {
  const [todos, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialTodos);

  const handleComplete = (todo) => {
    dispatch({ type: "COMPLETE", id: todo.id });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {todos.map((todo) => (
        <div key={todo.id}>
          <label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              checked={todo.complete}
              onChange={() => handleComplete(todo)}
            />
            {todo.title}
          </label>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Todos />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I am trying to test this component with jest. How to mock the useReducer hook here so that I can change the state of the component manually rather than changing it by clicking the checkbox.

I have tried some examples but unfortunately it did not work. Please suggest.

Comment: @remolten, could you please help here?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own test based on this test:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';

let someValue = 1;
const someDispatch = () => { };
const useReducer = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => [someValue, someDispatch]);
jest.spyOn(React, 'useReducer').mockImplementation(useReducer); // mocked the useReducer hook

describe('Some Test', () => {
    it('renders', () => {
        const { container, rerender } = render((
            <YourComponent />
        ));
        someValue = 3; // change state
        rerender(( // rerender with new state
            <YourComponent />
        ));
        expect(container).toMatchSnapshot(); // or your another expect
    });
});
```

Most likely, the component can be rendered in a simpler way. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Work like a charm! <3